# Adding a Whatsapp share Button (with javascript) inside a wordpress post

Tags: javascript, wordpress, button, share, whatsapp

Im not very smart with coding so I hope very much someone could help me.
I wanna implement a whatsapp share button within a wordpress text. (WITHOUT A PLUGIN.)
I have got this beauty here. But wordpress always remove the inline javascript after saving it.

```
<a href="" target="_blank" onclick="this.href='https://wa.me/?text=Have a look at:'+location.href">WA</a>
```

at least it will not function anymore than (onclick).

Is there another solution to place a whatsapp share button within a wordpres text. maybe a solution without slowing down the side too?

thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use this plugin for sharing https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpupper-share-buttons/

Comment: with wordpress, always consider extending your site with plugins first. If what you want achieved isn't doable with any of the available plugins then you go ahead to write your plugin.

Comment: Thank you but im happy with my sharing plugin monarch as its very fast and has share counting. only its missing the whatsapp button so I need it within the text.

Comment: You have to encode the URL first. Your text contains space and colon. Have you checked whether the `onclick` attribute still exists or not?

Comment: thank you. how would this look like? im really not into coding sorry. thank you very much.

Comment: Can you search in your page's source code to see whether the `onclick` attribute still exists or not?

Comment: thanks. yes its not existing anymore its looking like this in the source code. so the javascript dissapeared. ``` <a class="whatsapp" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">WA</a> ```